# How to get Time zone based on region in azure using azure .Net SDK/Fluent API/ REST API?

Tags: azure, azure-search-.net-sdk, azure-management-api

I am doing auto-shutdown for VM using ARM template with .Net core Now I want to show dropdown for time zone which azure portal show based on VM deployed in which Region .
I am attaching screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The REST API endpoint

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{yourSubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{yourResourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{yourVMName}?$expand=instanceView&api-version=2020-12-01
```

should return something including:

```json
        "osProfile": {
            "computerName": "computername",
            "adminUsername": "adminusername",
            "windowsConfiguration": {
                "provisionVMAgent": true,
                "enableAutomaticUpdates": true,
                "patchSettings": {
                    "patchMode": "AutomaticByOS"
                }
            },
```

Now, you don't see `timeZone` there - the REST API documentation says it should be under `windowsConfiguration`. I'm speculating that it may be missing because I haven't changed anything, and that it is defaulting.

You can also run

```
$vm = Get-AzVM -Name {vmName}
$vm.OSProfile.WindowsConfiguration
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I want all time zone if VM is deployed on West US and also i ran the above command but timezone property is showing null

Comment: I agree with @DnyaneshwarSuryawanshi, it is null